# Create calculated field with condition from another column

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have data that shows student name and the years they attended the school along with the grades they achieved each year.

I need to visualize this in a horizontal bar graph with names on the y-axis and grades on the x-axis

My dataset looks somewhat like this:

| name | Year | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2016 | 79 |
|  | 2017 | 65 |
| Smith | 2018 | 87 |
|  | 2019 | 56 |
| Mary | 2017 | 92 |
| Jack | 2016 | 95 |
|  | 2017 | 75 |

I want a dropdown/parameter based on the year that changes my data in a way that shows, The names and grades of the selected year only.

So if I were to select 2017, I want the data to look like this:

| Name | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| John | 65 |
| Mary | 92 |
| Jack | 75 |

I've tried something like this with no luck in the 'create calculated field' dialog box:

> If [Parameters].[By Year] == "2017"
> THEN
> [Name] = WHEN [year] = "2017"
> END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your calculated field (for filter) should be like this:

```
IF [Year] = [Parameters].[By Year] 
     THEN [Grade]
ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, did you try the solution ?