# how can i visualized my 2023 parameter on tableau after i have found the year different

Tags: visualization, tableau-desktop, calculated-field, tableau-prep

Tableau visualization

i tried this but 2023 column did not calculate rather just giving out negative values in tabeau
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2013 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2014 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2015 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2016 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2017 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2018 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2019 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2020 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2021 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2022 THEN [Name] END) - COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)
+
COUNTD(IF [Year] = 2023 THEN [Name] END)

[This what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbfhZ.png)

[This is what i expect to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtWkF.png)

Comment: Can you please explain your question in more detail and add context? What are you specifically trying to accomplish? Other than the code above, what else have you tried? Please see [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for reference. This will help people in getting you the answer you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create calculated field with condition from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74283035/create-calculated-field-with-condition-from-another-column)